# vb.net remove both duplicate and original record in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

How do I remove the record in listview if the record has a duplicated one? and it will also delete the original one. For example:

```
Column1  
AAA       
BBB      
CCC     
AAA       
DDD
```

In this case, both the first and fourth one will be deleted.
The final output will be

```
Column1

BBB     
CCC    
DDD
```

Please help, Thank you.

I tried this one

```
dim ctr as integer
dim ctr2 as integer

ctr = 0
Do
  ctr2 = 0
  Do
    If ListView3.Items.Item(ctr).Text = ListView3.Items.Item(ctr2).Text And ListView3.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text = ListView3.Items(ctr2).SubItems(1).Text Then
      ListView3.Items(ctr).Remove()
      ListView3.Items(ctr2).Remove()
    End If
    ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
  Loop Until ctr = ListView3.Items.Count


  ctr = ctr + 1
Loop Until ctr = ListView3.Items.Count
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve relative order of the items?

Comment: No, i just need to remove duplicated and the original one

Comment: Why are there duplicate items in the `ListView` in the first place?  Is it possible to prevent them being added rather than removing them afterwards?  That would be preferable if it's feasible.

Comment: it's confusing me because the records came from 4 Listview with different subitems. But if that's the best solution, can you guide me? Im still at the learning phase in vb.net. Please i really need some help. Im stuck here. Thanks

Comment: When merging the 4, simply look to see if that data already exists in the Dest LV and decline to add it when it does.  Much easier to keep dupes out at the start than finding and removing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your code i understand that list  view have  two columns , and you want to delete rows that are duplicate .

so first thing you must not delete from list view direct when you find duplicate row because it make problem for sort items and list.
Example: you have following list
AA
BB
CC

CC item have index=2 , if you delete BB item , CC will have index=1.

this is modifying for your code to delete duplicate rows.

```
   Dim ctr As Integer
        Dim ctr2 As Integer
        Dim RemovedItemsIndexs As New Collection

        ctr = 0
        Do
            ctr2 = 1
            Do
                If ListView3.Items.Item(ctr).Text = ListView3.Items.Item(ctr2).Text And ListView3.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text = ListView3.Items(ctr2).SubItems(1).Text Then
                    If Not RemovedItemsIndexs.Contains(ctr) Then
                        RemovedItemsIndexs.Add(ctr, ctr)
                    End If
                    If Not RemovedItemsIndexs.Contains(ctr2) Then
                        RemovedItemsIndexs.Add(ctr2, ctr2)
                    End If
                End If
                ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
            Loop Until ctr2 = ListView3.Items.Count


            ctr = ctr + 1
        Loop Until ctr = ListView3.Items.Count


        For index As Integer = 1 To RemovedItemsIndexs.Count
            ListView3.Items.RemoveAt(RemovedItemsIndexs(index))
        Next
```

last thing i want say ,you must check if sub item is exist before you use  for example if ListView3.Items(ctr2).SubItems(1) not exist it will throw exception